# Enable Firefox Menu Button in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox

Is there a way to enable the big (orange) menu button in Firefox for *OS X* (per config setting or extension)? I know there is the menubar of course, but the compact menu is so convenient.

What I mean in Windows, Linux:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that firefox works with Aqua on OS/X, this isn't available like it is on Windows or Gnome. However, you probably can emulate the behavior with an add-on like the following:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-caption-titlebar-plus-sma/

Comment: that particular addon is sadly not compatible with OS X